# Serialize Jackson field in two different ways

Tags: java, json, mongodb, serialization, jackson

I am doing POJO serialization / deserialization using Jackson.
Here is a POJO exemple :

```
public class Pojo {
    public String productId;
    public String name;
}
```

I have to read the field `productId` in this JSON :

```
{"productId":"1","name":"exemple"}
```

But also in :

```
{"_id":"1","name":"exemple"}
```

To make it short, I would like to use the same object to read the field in a JSON file found somewhere and to save the object as this in MongoDB, using `productId` as the primary key, which has to be named `_id`.
Since I am using Jackson (fasterxml) both to read from the file and to write to the database, I can not find a way to do so, except by creating a new class with the same fields (or inheritance) and fill them one by one. Basically, I would like to find a way to put 2 @JsonProperty annotations on `productId`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize one class in two different ways with Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141561/serialize-one-class-in-two-different-ways-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

Works with both strings:

```
public class Pojo {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String productId;
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("productId")
    public void setProductId(String id) {
        productId = id;
    }

}
```